# Pacemaker resource stopping and starting between during state change

Tags: heartbeat

Observing  resource being stopped and started while changing state from managed to unmanaged and reverse.

mysql[20932]: 2012/09/01_11:17:03 INFO: MySQL started

Is it normal or I need to look into any spcific config on my cluster. Running heartbeat 3.0.3 and pacemaker 1.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

Changing from managed to unmanaged shouldn't start or stop resources. But have a look at the changelog of pacemaker 1.0.12: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker-1.0/blob/master/ChangeLog
"High: PE: Ensure role is preserved for unmanaged resources"

So maybe you hit a bug. I recommend upgrading to 1.0.12, maybe even to the current 1.1.x version of pacemaker.